# Android Wear onEnterAmbient() not being called on all devices

Tags: android, wear-os

Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/views/always-on) states

> When the activity switches to ambient mode, the system calls the onEnterAmbient() method of your ambient callback

The problem I am encountering is that is not always the case

Running the following code on the Android Studio Emulator and a Fossil Gen 6 watch (Wear OS 3) works perfectly

But when the same code is run on a Samsung Galaxy Watch 4 (Wear OS 3) or a TicWatch Pro 3 (Wear OS 2) onEnterAmbient() is not called.

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), AmbientCallbackProvider {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var ambientController: AmbientModeSupport.AmbientController 
    private var systemOneSecondTick: Timer = Timer()
    private var bottomKeyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_STEM_1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ambientController = AmbientModeSupport.attach(this)

        // Samsung assigns different button codes
        if (Build.MODEL == "SM-R870") {
            bottomKeyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
        }

        systemOneSecondTick.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
            runOnUiThread {
                binding.middleLineTextView.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.UK).format(System.currentTimeMillis())
            }
                                                          }, 0, 1000)

    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        return if (keyCode == bottomKeyCode) {
            true // indicates key press has been handled
        } else {
            super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
        }
    }

    override fun getAmbientCallback() = object : AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallback() {
        override fun onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails: Bundle?) {
            // This is not called on all devices
            super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails)
            binding.middleLineTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(150,150,150))
            Log.d(TAG, "onEnterAmbient()")
        }

        override fun onExitAmbient() {
            // This is called !!!!
            super.onExitAmbient()
            binding.middleLineTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,255,255))
            Log.d(TAG, "onExitAmbient()")
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "WearAmbientMode"
    }
}
```

The very simple example only attempts to dim the colour of the displayed time (for the purpose of keeping it simple it does not even attempt to slow down the clock updates)

On the emulator and Fossil watch covering the watch face results in onEnterAmbient() being called and display shows dimmed time. By pressing the bottom key onExitAmbient() is called and the display is returned to full brightness

On the Galaxy Watch 4 and TicWatch Pro 3 covering the watch face results in the display being turned off. The log shows onEnterAmbient() has not been called. Pressing the bottom button results in onExitAmbient() being called (although a possibly separate issue is this is not always the case with the Galaxy Watch)

I have tried changing the always on display setting on the Galaxy Watch 4 but onEnterAmbient() is still not triggered

Can anyone suggest why the code works as designed on the emulator and Fossil watch but not on the Galaxy Watch 4?

Comment: Did you enable "Ambient" in Settings? As I kown, it was disable by default on TicWatch Pro 3.

Comment: @Yong - Yes I tried Settings -> Display -> Always On Display but enabling / disabling it does not fix the reported issue. Covering the watch face (palm gesture) results in the watch face turning off with no call to onEnterAmbient.